# What is sqlmodel.sql.sqltypes.AutoString()?

Tags: python, alembic

I am using Alembic and it creates String field like that:

```
    sa.Column('description', sqlmodel.sql.sqltypes.AutoString(), nullable=False),
```

I am not able to find, what AutoString that is. What is the difference to sqlalchemy.String()?

Comment: source code for [AutoString](https://github.com/tiangolo/sqlmodel/blob/main/sqlmodel/sql/sqltypes.py#L10) - I never used it but word `auto` suggests that it sets something automatically if you don't set it manually. Source code suggests that it uses normal `String` and it sets automatically length `255` (for `mysql`)

Comment: Yeah, that is what I thought when I found the source, but it just did not make much sense for me. Thanks.